# How to make a shared legend with matplotlib's subplot functionality?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would appreciate some assistance generating two legends to be shared amongst four subplots in one figure. I'm finding most examples use explicit legend labels, which is very unhelpful for a lot of real-world data problems. I don't expect you to run the code (if it helps, I can't release any of the real data), just some suggestions would do fine.

Until I run the code I **do not know** how many unique covariate values I will have. Hence, I can't explicitly define legend labels (and even if I did, I would never explicitly list them as my code would be constrained). The only data I do know is `adjustedMEAResultList` which holds explicit marker value per `projectedArray[0:,i]` element and it never changes; it results in the square and circle distinction you can make out.

I would like to see two legends, anywhere that doesn't cover up a plot.

**Legend 1:**

Circle = "MEA fail"
Square = "MEA hit"

**Legend 2:**

Each colour represents a value somewhere between 0 and 9. Again, this can't be explicit. When I add further samples, the numbers could change.

My code:

```
#function taken from a Matplotlib github comment (due to matplotlib's marker limitation)
def mscatter(x,y,ax=None, m=None, **kw):
    import matplotlib.markers as mmarkers
    if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
    sc = ax.scatter(x,y,**kw)
    if (m is not None) and (len(m)==len(x)):
        paths = []
        for marker in m:
            if isinstance(marker, mmarkers.MarkerStyle):
                marker_obj = marker
            else:
                marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)
            path = marker_obj.get_path().transformed(
                        marker_obj.get_transform())
            paths.append(path)
        sc.set_paths(paths)
    return sc

#Calculate the 4 PC plots 
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,(i+1))
    numRingsList = [int(n) for n in numRingsList]

    scatter = mscatter(x=projectedArray[0:,i], y=projectedArray[0:,(i+1)], 
                c=numRingsList, edgecolor='k', m=adjustedMEAResultList,
                cmap=plt.cm.nipy_spectral, alpha=0.7)
    plt.xlabel("PC" + str((i+1)))
    plt.ylabel("PC" + str((i+2)))
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.suptitle("Chemical similarity: MEA results\n2D Pharmacophore fingerprint with Tanimoto scores\nNumber of Rings", fontsize=14)

#Junk for Jupyter Notebook    
plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0, h_pad=0, w_pad=0) #w_pad=0.1, h_pad=0.1)
fig.set_size_inches(12.0, 12.0, forward=True)
```

This is what I currently have:
[image]

Comment: You can use proxy artists to do both of these; the [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) shows how you can do that; for legend 1 its a simple case of created two proxies (a square and a circle), for legend 2 I think you can just create proxies with different colours based on your data

Comment: Thanks @tmdavison - I'm looking into marker only patches (the example the page gives is a line with symbol/marker), but I'm finding matplotlib to be so draining, I've half the mind to import everything into R. Sad times.

Comment: just all `linestyle='None'`